# Laravel 4 - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been working with Laravel 4.1 to create a book list app with user relationships.  I have the user relationships working however when I added the pagination I get the following Error Exception:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /app/views/books/index.blade.php)

return link_to_route('user.books.show', $book->title, [$book->user->username, $book->id]);
```

The error generates from the view (book/index.blade.php)  but the error exception actually comes from the helper (see below).

[image: Helpers.php - Line 11 generates the error]

**Controller - PARTIAL**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $book = Book::findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('books.show', compact('book'));
}
}
```

**My Route File**

is set up to force the address to be the USERNAME>BOOKS>BOOK_ID:

```
#Books Controller

Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');

Route::get('books/{id}', 'BooksController@show')->where('id', '\d+');

//Books ID Rerouting  - USERNAME -> BOOK -> Book ID

Route::get('{username}/books', 'UserBooksController@index');

Route::get('{username}/books/{id}', ['as' => 'user.books.show', 'uses' => 'UserBooksController@show']);
```

Which is where I am getting the error - it no longer recognizes

```
user.books.show
```

**books/index.blade.php file**

```
    @foreach(array_chunk($books->getCollection()->all(), 3) as $row)    

    <div class="row">

    @foreach ($row as $book)

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
         <img data-src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ link_to_book($book) }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $book->synopsis }} </p>
            <p><a href="{{ link_to_book($book) }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy Now</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach     

{{ dd(Request::only('1')) }}    

{{ $books->appends(Request::only('1'))->links() }}
```

**HELPER FILE**

```
<?php


function link_to_book(Book $book)

{
    return link_to_route('user.books.show', $book->title, [$book->user->username, $book->id]);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have code for multiple pages here. Can you clean it up and reduce everything to ONLY the code that affects the page where your error is? Similarly, is the `link_to_route` the line where the error is happening? Because you don't show where that is in your view files here. Needs to be clarified.

Comment: The View File is listed in its entirety - it is the route file it pulls the user.books.show object from which is causing the issue.

I have removed the model and cleaned up the controller to only the necessary sections.

Thank you!

Comment: I still don't get exactly what line the error is happening on.

Comment: Is it possible that $book->user could be null?

Comment: I don't think so, it was working before I added pagination into the mix.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same issue and that's how I resolved it. To access the elements in the array, use array notation: `$book['image']`

`$book->image` is object notation, which can only be used to access object attributes and methods.
try this:

```
 @foreach(array_chunk($books->getCollection()->all(), 3) as $row)    

    <div class="row">

    @foreach ($row as $book)

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
         <img data-src="{{ $book['image'] }}" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ link_to_book($book) }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $book['synopsis'] }} </p>
            <p><a href="{{ link_to_book($book) }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy Now</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach     

{{ dd(Request::only('1')) }}    

{{ $books->appends(Request::only('1'))->links() }}
```

That should resolve it. What its saying is that you are calling a non object in a way that should only be used for objects. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a lot of time. I wasn't getting why I was getting this error.

Answer (score 7):

Try output gettype($book), if you get null in any point

```
{{$book['image']}} //will not complain about it but gives output ""
{{$book->image}} //will complain about it and throws an exception
```

I think that's the reason

I'm using laravel5 but I think it is the same with laravel4

Comment: Very nice, though I was looking for something else but the solution provided by you is a good one and will come handy in many scenarios. Thanks - Sambhav