# laravel send empty object to view

Tags: php, object, laravel

hi in my appliation i have a home view where i load the last things that happened since last login 
it's like

```
 Le 2014-11-30, à 00:00:00, test ADMIN a appelé le dépanneur monoprix.
 Le 2015-11-30, à 14:32:25, vous avez reçu une nouvelle demande de devis de test ADMIN.
 Le 2014-11-30, à 11:27:25, test ADMIN a laissé un commentaire sur xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
 Le 2014-10-20, à 08:31:24, vous avez reçu une nouvelle demande de création de compte.
 Le 2014-11-30, à 10:00:00, Société xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx a envoyée une nouvelle demande tarifaire pour la   demande fuite d'eau
 Le 1970-01-01, à 00:00:00, Société xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx a refusé la demande de devis pour fuite d'eau
```

and here is the code

```
$homeCalls = Call::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $homeDemands = Quote::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $homeInscription = Repairman::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->Where('statut', 0)->first();
    $homeTariff = DB::table('Quote_repairman')->where('tariff','!=', '')->where('sent','!=', 1)->where('state','=', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();    
    $homeDeny = DB::table('Quote_repairman')->where('tariff', NULL)->where('state', 2)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();    
    $homeComments =  DB::table('Particular_repairman')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();     

    return View::make('home.home')
    ->with('homeDemands', $homeDemands)
    ->with('homeTariff', $homeTariff)
    ->with('homeDeny', $homeDeny)
    ->with('homeInscription', $homeInscription)
    ->with('homeComments', $homeComments)
    ->with('homeCalls', $homeCalls);
```

the problem is that when the database is empty i get an error Trying to get property of non-object !! how i resolve this problem ?? thx

Comment: have you checked this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923931/laravel-4-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object seems like same issue

Answer (score 0):

We need to see how you call the data that is causing the error in your view.
It's probably caused by one of two possible things:

Alt 1. The same issue that engvrdr linked to in the comment above (mixing how to fetch data from arrays vs. objects)

Alt 2. Trying to fetch data from an empty resultset. If that's the case, you should be able to get around it with a simple

```
@if ( $homeDemands && $homeDemands->row_count() > 0 ):
    {{ $homeDemands->your_column_name }}
@endif
```

(some kind of lookup could / should be used for all resultsets)