# Typo3 9.5 why can't you see on what page the error is at?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Why can't  you see exactly where the error is thrown with Typo3? Like with Laravel. When an error is shown it usually also shows on what PAGE CLASS or FUNCTION that error is made....

Is it possible, to change that? With an extension or something?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation about [Error and Exception Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Index.html) on how to configure this to display all error details locally but only show a human readable error on production.

Comment: When there's an error in one of the templates, I want it to show which template. Look at image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923931/laravel-4-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object